# Vim: arrow keys to move within a line in insert mode

Tags: vim

I have `<Up>` and `<Down>` nnoremapped to `gk` and `gj` but this won't let me use them while in edit mode. I tried using inoremap but that just types out `gk` or `gj`.

So I could certainly do something like `inoremap <Up> <ESC>gki`. Is this the best and only reasonable way to do it? I don't like this method because it isn't apparent to somebody reading the settings file what it does. Not that I could say that about any bit of vim setting file I have ever seen.

Comment: "it isn't apparent to somebody reading the settings file what it does" Why not? You've surely written what it does in a comment above this line, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To execute a normal mode command in insert mode, use
<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>. Straight from the [help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-O):

```
CTRL-O      execute one command, return to Insert mode   *i_CTRL-O*
```

So something like this:

```
inoremap <Up>   <C-O>gk
inoremap <Down> <C-O>gj
```

Might be more readable.

Comment: Sorry @Steven Lu, I didn't understand you question correctly at first glance but now I updated the wording.